# Why would memory alloc/freeing fail in a 32-bit plug-in running in a 64-bit app but not in a 32-bit app?

Tags: macos, plugins, new-operator, 32bit-64bit, delete-operator

I'm developing audio plug-ins for both Windows and Mac (VST and AU), and I've run into a problem that only occurs when opening the plug-in in a 64-bit host DAW (in my case Reaper) in OSX 10.8.

The plug-in is a universal binary build and works fine in 32-bit hosts, but opening it in Reaper 64-bit causes it to crash on random new/delete instructions that allocate filter objects.  I tried building it as a 64-bit plug-in just to test, but the same thing happened.

What could cause this to happen?

Edit: Here is a screen capture of the crash report:
[image]

Comment: I literally just posted the exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309065/64-bit-build-in-osx-inconsistant-malloc-error)

Let me know if you find the answer and I'll do the same.

Comment: I'd guess the 32/64-bit issue is a red herring. There's probably some other memory bug in your program that is messing up the internal state of the memory allocator, but for some reason it only semi-readily manifests itself on your 64-bit host. Memory bugs can be tricky like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue causing the random memory error when using a 64-bit host.  There was a memset function that referenced the size of the pointer, declared as float, to clear it's contents.  Of course on a 64-bit host the pointer size is 64 bits and so the memset function corrupted the heap, leading to the fickle memory errors.

This was the memset function:

```
float *z;
//...
memset(z, 0, sizeof(z)*size);
```

The intention was that should z eventually declared a double, it would be automatic in this function to adjust the block of memory allocated. I overlooked what would happen in a 64-bit context.

Comment: sizeof should work in 32 and  64 bit... Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: But it's sizeof a pointer. No matter that the pointer is declared as pointing to a float, the size of the pointer 'address' is 32 bits in a 32-bit system, yet 64 bits in a 64-bit system even though the variable size it points at is 32 bits.